# Is the map $\rho\rightarrow Tr(\sigma\rho)$ completely positive?

Tags: quantum-operation

Let $\sigma$ be a fixed positive semidefinite matrix (edit: need unit trace too as pointed out if we want trace nonincreasing). Is the map

$$N:H\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$$

given by $N(\rho) = Tr(\sigma\rho)$ completely positive? Note that it is positive and trace nonincreasing. If yes, what are its Kraus operators?

Comment: Why trace nonincreasing? If $\sigma=  \begin{matrix}
   2 & 0\\
   0 & 2\\
  \end{matrix} \tag{1}$ and $\rho=\begin{matrix}
   1 & 0\\
   0 & 0\\
  \end{matrix} \tag{2}$  Then $Tr(\sigma\rho)=2$.

Comment: @narip that's of course only true if $\sigma$ has trace one.

Comment: $\sigma$ can't be equal to $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ if $\sigma$ is to be a valid density matrix

Comment: @GaussStrife but the assumption was only psd ... so narip is correct

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich correct. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the composition of 2 maps: $x \rightarrow \sqrt{\sigma}x\sqrt{\sigma}$ and $x \rightarrow \text{Tr}(x)$. Both are completely positive.

The first map is already in the Kraus decomposition form.
For the second map we can take the decomposition $\text{Tr}(x) = \sum_i \langle  i |x|i\rangle$.

So, the Kraus operators for the whole map are $A_i = \langle  i | \sqrt{\sigma} : H\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: These wouldn't satisfy the completeness relation though, correct? $\sum_{i}A_{i}^\dagger A_{i}=\sigma$

Comment: @GaussStrife Yes, the completeness relation is equivalent to the preservation of trace.

Comment: ah I see. I made the assumption that the map they were referring to was a Quantum Map, which it clearly can't be due to violation of the completness relation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is. Let's show this by computing the Choi state of $N$:
$$
\mathcal{J}(N) = \sum_{i,j} N(|i\rangle\langle j|) \otimes |i\rangle\langle j| = \sum_{i,j} \langle j|\sigma|i\rangle |i\rangle\langle j| = \sigma^T.
$$
Since the transposition map ${}^T$ is positive (btw not *completely* positive), $\sigma^T$ is a positive semi-definite operator and thus $N$ is CP.

Comment: Thank you - I had to pick one answer but yours was also super helpful and a nice way to see it